# Install4j: Changing Application Properties During Installation

Tags: java, install4j, software-distribution, highdpi

[image]

The software I am working on uses high-dpi scaling and I have noticed that some users specifically on higher res screens are having issues seeing font sizes within the software. This seemed to be fixed by going into the application properties and overriding the high dpi scaling behavior. My question is within install4j is there a way to add this property change during the installation process so that a user doesn't have to manually make this change?

Comment: By "application properties", do you mean the "DPI Awareness" setting in the "Executable info->Windows manifest options" step of the launcher wizard?

Comment: @IngoKegel Yes I am trying to override high dpi scaling within the application's properties. I will take a look at the windows manifest options within the GUI and see if this can work for me.

Comment: Hi, is there any follow-up on this? My application is having the same issue.